# How to hide a particular enum value from llvm Command Line help string?

Tags: c++, llvm

I am using llvm CommandLine library for argument parsing in one of my C++ projects. It has an option which accepts multiple logging levels, which is of `enum` type as below:

```
enum LogLevels {
    error,
    critical_warnings,
    all_warnings,
    info,
    trace
};

cl::OptionCategory Logging("Verbose Options:");

cl::opt<LogLevels> verbose("logging", cl::desc("Control logging levels:"),
        cl::values(
            clEnumValN(error,"error-only", "Level:1 - Report fatal errors"),
            clEnumValN(critical_warnings,"critical-warnings", "Level:2 - Report critical warnings and errors (default)"),
            clEnumValN(all_warnings, "all-warnings", "Level:3 - Report all warnings and errors"),
            clEnumValN(info, "info", "Level:4 - Report info messages along with error/warnings"),
            clEnumValN(trace, "trace", "Level:5 - Report all internal/developer details in logs")),
            cl::init(LogLevels::critical_warnings), cl::cat(Logging)
        );
```

How can I hide a particular `enum` value from user help string (output of `-help`) but still continue to accept it? In this case, I want to hide "trace" from the user help string and still continue to accept `--logging=trace` for internal use only.

I tried looking at https://llvm.org/docs/CommandLine.html# but couldn't figure it out. I need something similar to the `cl::Hidden` or `cl::ReallyHidden` modifiers, but for `enum` values.

Current output from `-help` is:

```
Verbose Options::

  --logging=<value>                                   - Control logging levels:
    =error-only                                       -   Level:1 - Report fatal errors
    =critical-warnings                                -   Level:2 - Report critical warnings and errors (default)
    =all-warnings                                     -   Level:3 - Report all warnings and errors
    =info                                             -   Level:4 - Report info messages along with error/warnings
    =trace                                            -   Level:5 - Report all internal/developer details in logs
```

Comment: What's the issue you face when using `cl::Hidden` option? It doesn't seem like the enum should make a difference.

Comment: ```cl::Hidden``` will cause the entire option to be hidden from the ```--help``` output and not just ```trace```. I want all other logging levels to still be visible except --logging=trace

Answer (score 2):

The `OptionEnumValue` applies to entire options, and as we can see from [the constructor of the `cl::opt` class template](https://llvm.org/doxygen/CommandLine_8h_source.html#l01490)

```
 template <class DataType, bool ExternalStorage = false,
           class ParserClass = parser<DataType>>
 class opt : public Option,
             public opt_storage<DataType, ExternalStorage,
                                std::is_class<DataType>::value> {
     // ...

     template <class... Mods>
     explicit opt(const Mods &... Ms)
         : Option(Optional, NotHidden), Parser(*this) {
       apply(this, Ms...);
       done();
     }

     // ...
 };
```

the mods (*values*, in the context of the OP) for a given option cannot, by themselves, hold a help visibility option; i.e., does not have its own [`cl::OptionHidden`](https://llvm.org/doxygen/CommandLine_8h_source.html#l00145) state.

I looks as if the only workaround to hide the `trace` option variant would be to remove the `trace` value from the `verbose` option and create it as a stand-alone `Hidden` option with no values/mods, say `--logging_trace`.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, there's no `cl::OptionHidden` for enum values (just the overall option).  Fortunately, the [llvm::cl::parser<>](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/master/include/llvm/Support/CommandLine.h#L764) class itself is a template , so we can specialize to do whatever we want.

If you look at the source for [generic_parser_base::printOptionInfo](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/master/lib/Support/CommandLine.cpp#L1864), you'll see what we really want to be able to specialize `shouldPrintOption()`, but that method is static...*weak sauce*. What *isn't* static is `getNumOptions()`. So we can do something like this:

```
#include <llvm/Support/CommandLine.h>


enum MyEnum{
  VISIBLE,
  HIDDEN
};

llvm::cl::opt<MyEnum> myOpt("myopt",
                            llvm::cl::values(
                                clEnumValN(MyEnum::VISIBLE,"visible", "Visible"),
                                clEnumValN(MyEnum::HIDDEN,"hidden", "Hidden")));

namespace llvm::cl{
template <> unsigned parser<MyEnum>::getNumOptions() const {
  return 1; // Lies!
}

}
```

This will get you almost all of the way there. The problem is the [generic_parser_base::findOption()](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/master/lib/Support/CommandLine.cpp#L1819), which uses `getNumOptions()` but is neither virtual nor templated. Fortunately, `findOption()` is only used two places `parser<>::addLiteralOption(...)` and `parser<parser>::removeLiteralOption(...)`, and these *are* templated, so we can specialize them (If you never remove options, then you can also skip the latter). For example:

```
#include <llvm/Support/CommandLine.h>

enum MyEnum{
  VISIBLE,
  HIDDEN
};

llvm::cl::opt<MyEnum> myOpt("myopt",
                            llvm::cl::values(
                                clEnumValN(MyEnum::VISIBLE,"visible", "Visible"),
                                clEnumValN(MyEnum::HIDDEN,"hidden", "Hidden")));

namespace llvm::cl{
template <> unsigned parser<MyEnum>::getNumOptions() const {
  return 1; // Lies!
}

template<>
template <class DT>
void addLiteralOption(StringRef Name, const DT &V, StringRef HelpStr) {
  //Commending out the findOption() check below:
  //assert(findOption(Name) == Values.size() && "Option already exists!");
  OptionInfo X(Name, static_cast<DataType>(V), HelpStr);
  Values.push_back(X);
  AddLiteralOption(Owner, Name);
}

}
```

This will allow you to use `--myopt=hidden` from the command line, but the `--help` output will only show something like:

```
 --myopt=<value>                   -
    =visible                       -   Visible
```